# GROUP BY on certain condition

Tags: mysql, group-by, case

I'm having some MySQL difficulties in the `GROUP BY` section of my query.
There is a column I would like to use in the `GROUP BY`, but that should only be used for a certain condition that depends on a value in a row. Let's say I have this table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test_table;
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I would like to retrieve all the rows, where it should only use `GROUP BY` on column c, when b === 1. That means I would like to get 6 rows back, because the rows number 2 and 3 should be grouped. So I came up with the following query, which doesn't give me the expected result.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test_table GROUP BY CASE WHEN b = 1 THEN c END;
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm probably missing something within the combination of the `CASE` statement and the `GROUP BY` and I hope any of you could help me out a bit.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: "That means I would like to get 5 rows back, because the rows number 2 and 3 should be grouped. " So the row with `| 3 | 1 | 2 |` should be 'missing'

Comment: Sure, I saw that. But it doesn't mean anything. What values do you expect to get from that group? The purpose of `GROUP BY` is not to ignore rows but to compute aggregate values from groups of rows. If you want to ignore the row with `a == 3` you can use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: What is the selection criteria when there are two or more rows having `b == 1` and the same value on column `c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `GROUP BY` clause with columns `b` and `c` separated by comma:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_table 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN b=1 THEN c ELSE a END;
```

**Result:**

```
A   B   C
1   1   1
2   1   2
4   2   2
5   2   3
6   3   1
7   2   2
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b873/11).

Comment: This query can ignore the row `| 2 | 1 | 2 |` as well (and return `| 3 | 1 | 2 |` instead). `SELECT`ing a column (`a` in this case) that is neither include in `GROUP BY` nor functionally dependent on those included is an error in standard `SQL`. It is accepted by MySQL but the result is **undefined behaviour**. It is [explicitly specified](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) in the documentation: *"the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate"*

Comment: That would not do the trick. If there would be another row with b = 2 and c = 2, that would be grouped with the row where a = 4.

Comment: I updated my question / example table. Of course in my case, this involves several `JOIN`s on different tables, which would make the real query a bit more difficult. But I would like to understand a bit how it works. The explanation on MySQL about `CASE` and `GROUP BY` are insufficient to me.

Comment: Thank you Raging Bull. Although in my case a `GROUP BY` on column a is dependent on another `CASE`, I think this would be the best approach. I got it working now the way I wanted.

Comment: @LaVomit: check this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1cb26/1). It's the same data in the table, the same query, but it returns a different result set.

Comment: @axiac: Please refer [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888082/which-record-will-group-by-choose-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

you may need to do something on these lines depending on your required output

```
SELECT c, count(*) FROM test_table where b=1 GROUP BY c
UNION 
SELECT c, count(*) FROM test_table where b<>1
```

Comment: That gives me the expected result indeed. Although I would like to seek an alternative to the use of `UNION`. As this refers to very large tables, it will take a while to execute. A `UNION` would make the query about twice as long (with all the `JOIN`s et cetera).

Comment: what column(s) are you aggregating?, I just used a group by c and count of rows.as an example. Could you please post your required output?